# How to get only directory name from SaveFileDialog.FileName

Tags: c#, string, parsing

What would be the easiest way to separate the directory name from the file name when dealing with `SaveFileDialog.FileName` in C#?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use:

```
System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(saveDialog.FileName)
```

(and the corresponding `System.IO.Path.GetFileName`). The Path class is really rather useful.

Answer (score 2):

You could construct a FileInfo object.  It has a Name, FullName, and DirectoryName property.

```
var file = new FileInfo(saveFileDialog.FileName);
Console.WriteLine("File is: " + file.Name);
Console.WriteLine("Directory is: " + file.DirectoryName);
```

Answer (score 1):

The Path object in `System.IO` parses it pretty nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Since the forward slash is not allowed in the filename, one simple way is to divide the SaveFileDialog.Filename using String.LastIndexOf; for example:

```
string filename = dialog.Filename;
string path = filename.Substring(0, filename.LastIndexOf("\"));
string file = filename.Substring(filename.LastIndexOf("\") + 1);
```